# Ondrop function unwillingly does 'view image'

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I want to implement an hello world when an dragged image is dropped on a target element. The code below works; when dragged image is dropped over target image, an alert box with hello world in it is displayed.

But, as soon as the alert box is clicked away. The image is displayed in a black window (as if someone clicked on left mouse button > view image). That is what i want to prevent. Does anyone know how to do that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Drag and Drop Demo</title>
    <script>
    function drag(ev) {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
        //alert(ev);
    } 

    function allowDrop(ev){
        ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function drop(ev) {
        alert('hello world');
        //ev.preventDefault();
        //var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
        //ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">

        <img src="1.jpg" draggable="true"></img>
        <img src="2.jpg" draggable="true"></img>
        <img src="3.jpg" draggable="true"></img>
        <img src="4.jpg" draggable="true"></img>
        <br><br>
        <img id="bin" src="bin.jpg" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></img>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First point is that the <img> tag does not require an end tag.

Comment: First point is that the <img> tag does not require an end tag. I tried your code in Firefox, IE, Chrome and Opera, you get the affect you state only in Firefox and Chrome. Changing Alert to console.log stops the affect in Chrome but not Firefox. Know that this does not help but may point those with more expertise in the right direction. This was meant to go with earlier comment but ran out of editing time.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. I just added the **preventdefault** method to the javascript function.

```
function drop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }
```